# How large of a hole can I cover with just 1/4" underlayment?

Tags: tiling, underlayment

I am redoing a bathroom and as such I am moving the shower feed piping (~3/4" holes), the drain (~2" hole), and also an air return (4x8" hole). I plan to use porcelain 12x24" tiles.

How big of a hole can I take up with the underlayment without having to add some sort of support structure, patch the subfloor, and then lay over top? I am assuming there's no issue with the small 3/4" holes, and I'm assuming I will have to patch the large air return hole, but the drain pipe hole is where I'm unsure. I'd like to avoid it as accessing it is going to be frustrating at best but would rather go through that than deal with cracked tiles.

The buildup will be: Joists, subfloor (broken with these holes), 1/4" underlay for the floor, and then an AlinO pre-fab shower pan and curb. It will line up that the curb will almost exactly cover the original air-return hole, but I'm not sure how solid they are, being foam.

Comment: Is there going to be a tub or counter over the hole? If in open even a 1/2” hole will show that thin of a overlay.

Comment: If you are to be putting your weight over a hole, your foot/heel right over it, might want more support.  2 inch hole and your heel probably will make a good size dip/dent in the floor, and that not good for tiles.

Comment: @EdBeal The plumbing holes will have a pre-fab shower pan that will then be tiled over. The air return hole will likely be under the shower curb (Alin-O pre-fab)

Comment: The pan and tile should be enough for the pipe holes